# Welche Rolle nimmt das Wort »dem« im folgenden Satz ein?

Tags: grammar-identification

Worauf bezieht sich das Wort *»dem«* im folgenden Text, bzw. welche Rolle nimmt es ein?

> [...] Damit wäre man in gewisser Weise freier, man wäre gezwungen, **dem** anderen aufrichtig zu begegnen und seine Handlungen zu kategorischen Imperativen zu machen. [...]

Comment: Don't post as picture, what you can post as text. Searchability and bandwidth is far better that way. (Your keyboard adds no useful information either).

Comment: @guidot: Why not _»Please don't ...«_?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains only a big image, but almost no text.

Comment: Regarding the actual question: "Zu wem gehört das Wort 'dem', das mit Blau selektiert ist": The question is not clear. What do you mean? Please describe your problem with more attention. Ideally, add your own hypotheses, this again will help us understand what's your problem.

Comment: Zur eigentlichen Frage: "Zu wem gehört das Wort 'dem', das mit Blau selektiert ist": Die Frage ist unklar. Was meinst du konkret? Bitte beschreibe dein Problem ausführlicher. Am besten fügst du noch deine eigenen Vermutungen oder Lösungsansätze hinzu; das hilft uns anderen, deine Frage zu verstehen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ich schlage vor, dass das Wort dem zu Menschen gehört, aber das Wort Menschen gelöscht wird weil man es verstehen kann, wenn er der ganze Satz lesen und aus diesem Grund wird das Pronomen anderem klein geschrieben

Comment: @user26646: Das musst du nicht mir, sondern dem Rechtschreibrat vorschlagen, die sehen das nämlich nicht so wie du. Siehe http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf In §57 (Seite 61-64) werden die Substantivierungen behandelt, in §58 (Seite 64-67) die Ausnahmen und die Ausnahmen von den Ausnahmen.

Comment: Danke Schön mein Lehrer @HubertSchölnast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dieser Satz stammt von einer [Website des Nachrichtenmagazins »Stern«](https://www.stern.de/panorama/wissen/natur/kw-04-2005-was-waere-alles-anders-in-der-menschlichen-gesellschaft--wenn-wir-die-gedanken-anderer--lesen--koennten---andrei--muenchen--3541530.html). Diese Seite enthält offenbar außer einer kurzen Einleitung nur Kommentare. Der Verfasser des nachgefragten Satzes war also aller Wahrscheinlichkeit nach kein Redakteur, und man kann daher nicht davon ausgehen, dass alles, was in solchen Kommentaren steht, richtig geschrieben ist.

Tatsächlich enthält dieser Satz einen Fehler. Das Wort »anderen« sollte groß geschrieben werden, denn es handelt sich hier um ein Substantiv, das von einem Infinitvpronomen abgeleitet wurde. Der Fachausdruck lautet *substantiviertes Infinitivpronomen*, aber dieser Ausdruck ist irreführend, weil das Wort eben *kein* Infinitvpronomen ist (sondern nur davon abstammt), sondern ein Substantiv, und daher muss es mit einem großem Anfangsbuchstaben geschrieben werden.

> Damit wäre man in gewisser Weise freier, man wäre gezwungen, dem **Anderen** aufrichtig zu begegnen und seine Handlungen zu kategorischen Imperativen zu machen.

Das Wort »dem«, das davor steht, ist nichts weiter als der Artikel der zu *»Anderem«* gehört:

> Nominativ: der Andere
>   Genitiv: des Anderen
>   Dativ: dem Anderen
>   Akkusativ: den Anderen

Das Verb *»begegnen«* verlangt sein Objekt im Dativ:

> Sie begegnet **dem Mann / der Frau / dem Kind.**

Daher muss die Nominalgruppe »der Andere« im Dativ verwendet werden:

> ... man wäre gezwungen, dem **Anderen** aufrichtig zu begegnen ...

Answer (score 2):

> Man wäre gezwungen, **dem anderen** aufrichtig zu begegnen.
>
> Man wäre gezwungen, **dem anderen Menschen** aufrichtig zu begegnen.
>
> Man müsste **dem anderen (Menschen)** aufrichtig begegnen.

Die Wortgruppe **dem anderen** ist das Dativobjekt im Infinitivsatz. Das Verb *begegnen* verlangt ein Dativobjekt. Es ist die Person, auf die man trifft.

Comment: Danke schön mein Lehrer

Comment: Wenn das Pronomen mit Artikel verwendet wird, dahinter aber kein Nomen (»Mensch«) steht, auf das sich der Artikel beziehen würde, ist das Pronomen substantiviert und muss daher groß geschrieben werden.

Comment: Mit Kontext (Stern, siehe Antwort von Hubert) stimme ich zu. Aber isoliert muss das keine Person sein. Statt "der Andere"/"der andere Mensch" könnte es auch "das Andere" (das, das anders ist) sein. In beiden Fällen natürlich der Fehler, dass "anderen" als Substantiv groß geschrieben sein müsste.